# Populating argument of float array as float* in C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, parameter-passing

I have this function like this:

```
bool funcFloats(float* output) {
     output = new float[100];
     populateArray((float *) &(*firstArray)[0], output); //First array is an std::vector<uint8_t>
     for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
         std::cout<<output[i]<<std::endl;
     }
}

template <typename A, typename B> void populateArray(A *in, B *out)
{
  using namespace std;
  for (unsigned y = 0; y < 100; y++)
    {
          out[y] = in[y];

    }
}
```

and I call it using this:

```
  float array[100];
  obj.funcFloats(array);
  for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    std::cout<<array[i]<<std::endl;
  }
```

and what's printed at the end of funcFloats is correct, but what's printed after the function is called is not. Why is this?

Comment: Post examples of correct and incorrect output.

Comment: `//populate array` part must be breaking it all. Please [edit] to show it as well.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight is it still possible that that could break it when I get the correct output at the end of that function?

Comment: First improvement you might want to do is: Never pass an array to a function without also passing its size. On second thought - never use raw arrays in the first place. ``std::vector<float>`` is your friend.

Comment: Where do you initialize the array?

Comment: Absolutely! For example, any assignment to `output` variable (as opposed to `output[i]`, which is fine) would be devastating for the caller, but OK for `funcFloat`'s consumption. (I KNEW IT!!!)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight wow, okay thanks!!! Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you assign `output` inside the function, making the array passed into `funcFloat` completely useless. It remains uninitialized when `funcFloat` exits, causing incorrect output.

Remove the assignment to `output` from `funcFloat` to fix this problem:

```
bool funcFloats(float* output) {
     output = new float[100]; // <<== Remove this line
     populateArray((float *) &(*firstArray)[0], output);
     for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
         std::cout<<output[i]<<std::endl;
     }
}
```

Although this would fix the immediate problem, the code would remain not C++-idiomatic. You should stay away from "raw" C-style arrays whenever possible, using vectors instead. This fixes multiple issues, such as the one you've seen, but also a possibility of array boundary mismatches (writing 1000 items into a 100-item array), possible memory leaks, and inability to grow an array dynamically.

Comment: Not to mention the very likely memory leak caused by unclear ownership. Allocate inside a function and hope those outside will free it is like laying a trap for someone - a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: @user7554160 You can do it using pointers to pointers: make `float *output` in main, and call `funcFloat(&output)`. Change `funcFloat` to take `float **outputPtr`, put back `float *output = new float[100];`, and add `*outputPtr = output;` after that.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> bool funcFloats(float* output) {
>      output = new float[100];
> ```

As already noted in another answer, you have a problem in the above `output` assignment. You dynamically allocate a `float` array with `new[]`, you assign the pointer to the first array element to the `output` variable, and doing so the *original* `output` array passed as parameter is lost after the assignment.

Note also that C++ doesn't have a garbage collector, so when you explicitly allocate memory with `new[]`, you should have code that *frees* that memory with `delete[]`.

A much better approach (that will make your code simpler), is to use `std::vector<float>` instead of a raw C-style array. This standard vector container will *automatically* release its own memory (so you don't have to pay attention to code doing that explicitly). And, if you want to pass to your function an *input/output* array parameter, you can pass a (non-const) reference to `std::vector`, e.g.:

```
bool funcFloats(std::vector<float> & output) {
  ...
```